# isolate similar data from stream

Tags: awk, sed, grep

We parse data of the following format -

```
35953539535393  BG  |..|...|REF_DATA^1^Y^|...|...| 
35953539535393  B  |..|...|REF_DATA_IND^1^B^|...|...|
```

We need to print unique values of REF_DATA* appearing in the file using script.
So,the output of the above data would be :

```
REF_DATA^1^Y^
REF_DATA_IND^1^B^
```

How do we achieve this using grep ,sed or awk - using a one-liner script.

Comment: use regex relying on `REF_` substring

Comment: add what you've tried.. if it is always 4th column, you could always separate out that column and then apply sort+uniq or use awk alone if you want to retain order

Comment: What Sundeep said. You've tagged your question with awk, sed and grep, so I'd expect to see examples or attempts using awk, sed and grep in your question. If you've done no work yourself, made no attempt to figure out a solution, then this isn't the right forum for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed & sort):

```
sed '/\n/!s/[^|]*REF_DATA[^|]*/\n&\n/;/^[^|]*REF_DATA/P;D' file | sort -u
```

Surround the intended strings by newlines, print only those strings on separate lines and sort those lines showing only unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'match($0,/REF_DATA[^|]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);if(!array[val]++){print val}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
match($0,/REF_DATA[^|]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  if(!array[val]++){
    print val
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have GNU grep:

```
command_to_produce_data | grep -oP '(?<=[|])REF_DATA.+?(?=[|])' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\| '{print $4}' file
REF_DATA^1^Y^
REF_DATA_IND^1^B^
```

Comment: Good solution but it will not cover the unique part of it I believe, you could pipe it to sort or unique too.